# dropdown working locally but not on server

Tags: jquery, symfony, bootstrap-4, symfony4

I create a website with symfony 4, and I use a bootstrap theme on it : https://www.gettemplate.com/info/progressus/

I finished the website, and everything works locally. But once I put it on my OVH server, my dropdown menu doesn't work anymore.

Locally :

[image: locally]

on the server (nothing happen) :

[image: server]

Here is my base.html.twig file, which contain all the common code, and in which the dropdown is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport"    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">

    <title>blog de frédéric - {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/favicon/site.webmanifest">

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- Custom styles for our template -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-theme.css" media="screen" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/perso.css">

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1ebe47041c.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

{% if path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')) == path('homepage') %}
    <body class="home">
{% else %}
    <body class="nothome">
{% endif %}

    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top headroom" >
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <!-- Button for smallest screens -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ path("homepage") }}">
                    <img src="/favicon/favicon.ico" alt="Frederic Malard">
                    <span class="titreNavbar d-block">Frédéric Malard</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                    {% if path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')) == path("drawings_index") %}
                        <li class="active">
                    {% else %}
                        <li>
                    {% endif %}
                        <a href="{{ path('drawings_index') }}">
                            Dessins
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    {% if path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')) == path("textes") %}
                        <li class="active">
                    {% else %}
                        <li>
                    {% endif %}
                        <a href="{{ path('textes') }}">
                            Textes
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    {% if path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')) == path("compos") %}
                        <li class="active">
                    {% else %}
                        <li>
                    {% endif %}
                        <a href="{{ path('compos') }}">
                            Compos
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    {% if path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')) == path("photos") %}
                        <li class="active">
                    {% else %}
                        <li>
                    {% endif %}
                        <a href="{{ path('photos') }}">
                            Photos
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            3D
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            Sites
                            <b class="caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="https://frederic-malard.com">
                                    portfolio
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="https://louvre.frederic-malard.com">
                                    louvre
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="#">
                                    blog personnel
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="https://ecrivain.frederic-malard.com">
                                    blog écrivain
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    {% if app.user %}
                        <li style="margin-left : -0.5em; margin-right : -0.5em;">
                            <a href="{{ path('account_logout') }}">
                                <img src="/images/connecte.png" alt="déconnexion" style="width : 1.5em; margin-top : -0.5em;">
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li class="dropdown" style="margin-left : -0.5em;margin-right : -0.5em;">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <img src="/images/deconnecte.png" alt="déconnexion" style="width : 1.5em; margin-top : -0.5em;">
                                <b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="{{ path("account_login") }}">
                                        Connexion
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="{{ path("account_register") }}">
                                        Inscription
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div> 
    <!-- /.navbar -->

    {% if path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')) == path('homepage') %}

    {% else %}
        <header id="head" class="secondary"></header>

        <div class="container">

            {# <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="active">About</li>
            </ol> #}
    {% endif %}

        {% block body %}{% endblock %}

    <!-- footer -->
    <div class="footer2">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-6 widget">
                        <div class="widget-body">
                            <p>
                                instagram : fred.dessins
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 widget">
                        <div class="widget-body">
                            <p class="text-right pFooterRight">
                                Copyright &copy; 2019, Frédéric Malard.<br>
                                Design partially based on template created by <a href="http://gettemplate.com/" rel="designer">gettemplate</a> 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div> <!-- /row of widgets -->
            </div>
        </div>

    </footer>   





    <!-- JavaScript libs are placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/headroom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jQuery.headroom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/template.js"></script>

        {#<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/poppers.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>#}


        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

I have no error messages.

Any idea please ?

Comment: You say theres no errors, but I can see several on your site. The most relevant of which is `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`. Check dev tools on your published site - the issues are because your site is HTTPS yet you're making calls to unsecure HTTP domains

Comment: Oh sorry, I checked my errors putting APP_ENV = dev in my .env file, I didn't thought about code inspector directly in navigator. Thank you, I just changed it and it works !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

to use https rather than http because your site is loading over https: and the browser won't load the http files because they are insecure content.